# Turning data with row/col index into table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data with position (row/column),

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'b02', 'b02', 'b02','b02', 'b02', 'b02', 'b02', 'b02'],
                   'Row': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'Col': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Result': ['p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p']})
```

and I am trying to turn it into tables, and calculate how many p and f in the table, like these:

```
ID: a01
p  f  p
p  p  f
p  p  p

p: 7 f: 2

ID: b02
p     p
p     f
p  p  p

p: 6 f: 1
```

There are some missing data, but the number of the row and column are fixed, so just leave them blank.

I have no idea how to achieve this, any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:
I did correct and input error in your input dataframe.
*(Changed the value in df.loc[8, 'ID'] from b02 to a01)*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'a01', 'b02', 'b02','b02', 'b02', 'b02', 'b02', 'b02'],
                   'Row': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'Col': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Result': ['p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'p']})

df

dfs = {}
for n, g in df.groupby('ID'):
    dfs[n] = g.pivot('Row', 'Col', 'Result').fillna('')
    print(f'ID: {n}')
    print(dfs[n])
    print('\n')
    print(dfs[n].stack().value_counts().to_dict())
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
ID: a01
Col  1  2  3
Row         
1    p  f  p
2    p  p  f
3    p  p  p


{'p': 7, 'f': 2}


ID: b02
Col  1  2  3
Row           
1    p     p
2    p     f
3    p  p  p


{'p': 6, 'f': 1}
```

---

Update to add concatenation and output to csv or excel.

```
pd.concat(dfs, keys=dfs.keys()).to_csv('out.csv')
!type out.csv
```

Output file contents:

```
,Row,1,2,3
a01,1,p,f,p
a01,2,p,p,f
a01,3,p,p,p
b02,1,p,,p
b02,2,p,,f
b02,3,p,p,p
```

Comment: @ Scott Boston - Is there any way to save the result as csv or excel file? I tried dfs.to_csv('Output.csv'), but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you want two different excel worksheets one for each dataframe, or would you like to concat the two dataframes together?  Yes, we can get the output dataframe(s) to a csv or excel.  Just let me know how you'd like to see them?

Comment: @ Scott Boston -- I would like to contact the two dataframes together. Thanks

Comment: @Joanne Look at update.... I used `pd.concat` to concatentation the dictionary entries together and use to_csv to create a file, you can use to_excel also.

Answer (score 2):

You can do [`.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on group

```
dt = df.groupby(['ID'])['Result'].value_counts().rename('count').reset_index()
print(dt)

    ID Result  count
0  a01      p      6
1  a01      f      2
2  b02      p      7
3  b02      f      1
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Do you know how to turn the data into table?

Comment: what do you mean by table?